# Is value returned by std::unique_ptr::get valid after moving unique_ptr?

Tags: c++11, move, unique-ptr

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class Owner {
public:
 Owner(std::unique_ptr<int> ptr) : owned_pointer<int>(std:move(ptr)) {}
private:
 std::unique_ptr<int> owned_pointer;
};


std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int);
int* ptr1 = ptr.get();
Owner new_owner(std::move(ptr));
```

Is it safe to assume that ptr1 is valid as long as new_owner stays in scope? It seems to work, but I can't find a specification that states that explicitly  - is it undefined behavior/implementation specific and just happen to work for me, or the code posted above is valid (ptr1 is guaranteed to point to moved pointer as long as it stays alive)?

Comment: `unique_ptr<int>` stores a value that is of type `int*`.  On destruction, it calls `delete` on it (through a traits class).  `ptr.get()` returns a copy of the `int*`.  `new_owner` transfers ownership of that `int*`, so the old `unique_ptr` won't `delete` it and the new one will.  Nothing magic should be going on.  Unless you are looking for a standardese tea leaf reading and are interested in possible holes/errors in the standard?

Comment: @Yakk, yes I am looking more for the standard specification or relevant stl documentation - I understand it is implemented as you described and hence it works. But I would like to guard against the possibility of next gcc release implementing unique_ptr differently and breaking the posted code - does the standard guarantee this to always work?

Comment: Honestly, it is pretty clear to me that this is one of the cases where if the standard disagrees with the implementation, the standard is wrong (wrt the lifetime of the `int*`).  This isn't like iterator abstractions around lifetime issues with vector, where practical and standard defined behavior can and probably should differ.  So any standard tea leaf reading that disagrees would just mean there is a bug in the standard.  I suppose such a bug in the standard, if not noticed, might lead gcc to implement the bug in a future iteration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the C++11 specification **guarantees** that transferring ownership of an object from one `unique_ptr` to another `unique_ptr` does not change the  location of the object itself, and that `get()` on the second `unique_ptr` returns the same as it would have on the first `unique_ptr` before the transfer.

Looking at N3337, section 20.7.1:

> 4. Additionally, `u` can, upon request, *transfer ownership* to another unique pointer `u2`. Upon completion of such a transfer, the following
>      postconditions hold:
>
>    - `u2.p` is equal to the pre-transfer `u.p`,
>    - `u.p` is equal to `nullptr`, and
>    - if the pre-transfer `u.d` maintained state, such state has been transferred to `u2.d`.

where `u` is a `unique_ptr` object that stores a pointer `u.p`.

The first bullet answers the question directly, since `get()` is specified as returning the `u.p`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is valid.

You can have multiple (plain) pointers pointing to the same object. The question is how long those pointers are valid or when the object pointed to is deleted.

A `unique_ptr` stores one more plain pointer and takes ownership, meaning it is responsible for when the object is destroyed. Moving it to another `unique_ptr` just transfers ownership, the object itself is still the same and all plain pointers pointing to it remain valid.

Only when the ownership is not transferred (or released) and the owning `unique_ptr` is destroyed, it also destroys the object. This would be the moment where all plain pointers pointing to the object become dangling pointers and dereferencing them would be illegal.

Comment: So does the standard really guarantee this or is it just coincidence that most implementations will show this behavior?

Comment: @Knitschi The question explicitly asked "is it undefined behavior/implementation specific and just happen to work for me, or the code posted above is valid". My answer says "Yes, it is valid." - even if it not explicitly stated anywhere, but the standard guarantees certain behaviour of `unique_ptr` as well as plain pointers and combining those, I think that the above is guaranteed to work.

Comment: So I wonder if your are sure because you read the standard (which I don't want to ;-) ) and it explicitly says that the the address returned by get() shall not change during a move, or just because you think that it is very unlikely that one would implement a unique_ptr that changes the address during a move?

Comment: @Knitschi "Change the address" does not make sense in this context. The object has an address, the `unique_ptr` does not move the object, it only moves its content - which is a pointer. If you have the same pointer, that pointer is a copy of the pointer the `unique_ptr` has. Whatever `unique_ptr` does with its own pointer will not affect yours - neither does it affect the object unless the `unique_ptr`, managing the object's lifetime (not its location), destroys the object.

Comment: Ok ok lets not argue over this any more. I accept that the managed pointer stays the same. My airliner avionics software will from now on rely on this and in case of a crash I will forward all email to you ;-)

Comment: @Knitschi No problem :) And if you are still worried, there is a simple test: Make the object unmoveable (and uncopyable). I often do this if I want to prevent accidential copy/move. Also, `unique_ptr` doesn't require the class that is points to to satisfy `Copyable` or `Moveable` concepts, so another "hint" that it is guaranteed to work :)

Comment: @DanielFrey Testing one implementation of std::unique_ptr on one machine with one compiler doesn't answer whether it's safe in other standards-compliant environments.

Comment: @mgiuffrida Of course not. But my answer is not "works for me", it explains how the concepts of the language guarantee that it works. Also about your suggested edit: The paragraph is to be read in context of the question. It does not explicitly mention that the pointer can't be deleted by other means (neither does your edit), but that it not relevant. The Q was about the unique_ptr and whether the other plain pointer is still valid while the (moved) unique_ptr is.