# Unique ptr move ownership to containing object's method

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I'd like to move unique_ptr to its object's method:

```
class Foo {
    void method(std::unique_ptr<Foo>&& self) {
        // this method now owns self
    }
}

auto foo_p = std::make_unique<Foo>();
foo_p->method(std::move(foo_p));
```

This compiles, but I don't know if it is not Undefined behavior. Since I moved from the object when also calling a method on it.

Is it UB?

If it is, I could probably fix it with:

```
auto raw_foo_p = foo_p.get();
raw_foo_p->method(std::move(foo_p))
```

right?

---

(Optional Motivation:)

Pass the object around to extend its lifetime. It would live in a lambda until the lambda would be called asynchronously. (boost::asio)
Please, see `Server::accept` first and then `Session::start`.

You can see the original implementation used shared_ptr, but I don't see why would that be justified, since I only need one owner of my Session object.

Shared_ptr makes code more complex and it was hard for me to understand, when not familiar with shared_ptr.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::system;
using namespace boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;


class Session /*: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>*/ {
public:
    Session(tcp::socket socket);

    void start(std::unique_ptr<Session>&& self);
private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string data_;
};

Session::Session(tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket))
{}

void Session::start(std::unique_ptr<Session>&& self)
{
    // original code, replaced with unique_ptr
    // auto self = shared_from_this();

    socket_.async_read_some(buffer(data_), [this/*, self*/, self(std::move(self))]  (error_code errorCode, size_t) mutable {
        if (!errorCode) {
            std::cout << "received: " << data_ << std::endl;
            start(std::move(self));
        }

        // if error code, this object gets automatically deleted as `self` enters end of the block
    });
}


class Server {
public:
    Server(io_context& context);
private:
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    void accept();
};


Server::Server(io_context& context) : acceptor_(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8888))
{
    accept();
}

void Server::accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code errorCode, tcp::socket socket) {
        if (!errorCode) {
            // original code, replaced with unique_ptr
            // std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket))->start();

            auto session_ptr = std::make_unique<Session>(std::move(socket));
            session_ptr->start(std::move(session_ptr));
        }
        accept();
    });
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    Server server(context);
    context.run();
    return 0;
}
```

compiles with:
`g++ main.cpp -std=c++17 -lpthread -lboost_system`

Comment: As you can see, the code hasn't become more simple and obvious after replacing shared_ptr with unique_ptr.

Comment: this method now owns self - no, it does not own. It's just a reference, no move performed. Yes, you may have UB, you call asynchronously the method just passing the reference, not transferring the ownership, depending on the variable life.

Comment: I can see no value in having a member of an object which is a `unique_ptr` to that object.  It just makes no sense.

Comment: @S.M. I mean it owns the handler. The object should be on heap until a `unique_ptr` pointing to it gets destructed, right?

Comment: @S.M. He actually transfers ownership into the lambda via capture, which will be stored somewhere in the boost internals. So I don't see any issue with the asynchronous call.

Comment: @PaulSanders It is not actually a member of itself, the owning `unique_ptr` is held somewhere in unrelated storage, OP is merely using a member function to generate the required lambda. It could have been done in a free function just as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first code block:

`std::unique_ptr<Foo>&& self` is a reference and assigning it an argument `std::move(foo_p)`, where `foo_p` is a named `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` will only bind the reference `self` to `foo_p`, meaning that `self` will refer to `foo_p` in the calling scope.

It does not create any new `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` to which the ownership of the managed `Foo` object may be transferred. No move construction or assignment happens and the `Foo` object is still destroyed with the destruction of `foo_p` in the calling scope.

Therefore there is no risk of undefined behavior in this function call itself, although you could use the reference `self` in a way that could cause undefined behavior in the body.

Maybe you intended to have `self` be a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<Foo>&&`. In that case `self` would not be a reference, but an actual object to which ownership of the managed `Foo` would be transferred via move construction if called with `std::move(p_foo)` and which would be destroyed after the function call in `foo_p->method(std::move(foo_p))` together with the managed `Foo`.

Whether this alternative variant is in itself potentially undefined behavior depends on the C++ standard version in use.

Before C++17 the compiler was allowed to choose to evaluate the call's arguments (and the associated move construction of the parameter) before evaluating `foo_p->method`. This would mean, that `foo_p` could have already moved from when `foo_p->method` is evaluated, causing undefined behavior. This could be fixed similarly to how you propose to do it.

Since C++17 it is guaranteed that the postfix-expression (here `foo_p->method`) is evaluated before any of the arguments of the call are and therefore the call itself would not be a problem. (Still the body could cause other issues.)

In detail for the latter case:

`foo_p->method` is interpreted as `(foo_p->operator->())->method`, because `std::unique_ptr` offers this `operator->()`. `(foo_p->operator->())` will resolve to a pointer to the `Foo` object managed by the `std::unique_ptr`. The last `->method` resolves to a member function `method` of that object. In C++17 this evaluation happens before any evaluation of the arguments to `method` and is therefore valid, because no move from `foo_p` has happened yet.

Then the evaluation order of the arguments is by design unspecified. So probably **A)** the unique_ptr `foo_p` could get moved from before `this` as an argument would be initialized. And **B)** it **will** get moved from by the time `method` runs and uses the initialized `this`.

But **A)** is not a problem, since § 8.2.2:4, as expected:

> If the function is a non-static member function, the **this** parameter of the function shall be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call,

(And we know this object was resolved *before* any argument was evaluated.)

And **B)** won't matter as: ([another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42990870/3791837))

> the C++11 specification guarantees that transferring ownership of an object from one unique_ptr to another unique_ptr does not change the location of the object itself

---

For your second block:

`self(std::move(self))` creates a lambda capture of type `std::unique_ptr<Session>` (not a reference) initialized with the reference `self`, which is referring to `session_ptr` in the lambda in `accept`. Via move-construction ownership of the `Session` object is transferred from `session_ptr` to the lambda's member.

The lambda is then passed to `async_read_some`, which will (because the lambda is not passed as non-const lvalue reference) move the lambda into internal storage, so that it can be called asynchronously later. With this move, the ownership of the `Session` object transfers to the boost::asio internals as well.

`async_read_some` returns immediately and so all local variables of `start` and the lambda in `accept` are destroyed. However the ownership of `Session` was already transferred and so there is no undefined behavior because of lifetime issues here.

Asynchronously the lambda's copy will be called, which may again call `start`, in which case the ownership of `Session` will be transferred to another lambda's member and the lambda with the `Session` ownership will again be moved to internal boost::asio storage. After the asynchronous call of the lambda, it will be destroyed by boost::asio. However at this point, again, ownership has already transferred.

The `Session` object is finally destroyed, when `if(!errorCode)` fails and the lambda with the owning `std::unique_ptr<Session>` is destroyed by boost::asio after its call.

Therefore I see no problem with this approach with regards to undefined behavior relating to `Session`'s lifetime. If you are using C++17 then it would also be fine to drop the `&&` in the `std::unique_ptr<Session>&& self` parameter.

Comment: Perfect! I forgot `std::unique_ptr<Foo>&&` would only reference the object until I actually move it – assign it – to a value type object. Of course I intended `self` be a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` in my first example!

Comment: I submitted an edit adding a more step-by-step explanation with debunked seemingly-pitfalls I found interesting and wanted to list them explicitly.